# How do i setup universal linking in a react native project that uses expo?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, ios-universal-links, create-react-native-app

I have followed the tutorial on expo's website to set up deep linking. What I have enables me to

> 1. Share content from my app
> 2. click a link in the message
> 3. Get redirected to the content in my app

The problem is that if the app is installed, the link is useless. This is why i want to set up universal linking

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: On the expo forum, I was directed to branch.io (https://forums.expo.io/t/how-do-i-deep-link-to-the-ios-store/7354/11)